# How to add native framework/library to flutter plugin(not by using cocoapods)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

I am new to Flutter. I am having native frameworks(both iOS & Android) which runs successfully with native projects. I need to create and incorporate these frameworks to the plugin, so that this plugin can be used in any Flutter projects to consume the functionalities of the frameworks.

Any help on achieving this will be helpful and appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: If not using a cocoapod  then add your framework each iOS/Android project(android/ios in flutter folder).

Comment: I am also in the same problem, do you have any information to share with me ?